# Nginx conf template not working with dokku

Tags: nginx, docker

I am stuck with the following nginx conf template:

```
# Special characters - dollar signs, spaces inside of quotes, etc. -
# should be escaped with a single backslash or can cause deploy failures.

server {
    listen      [::]:80;
    listen      80;
    server_name $NOSSL_SERVER_NAME;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/${APP}-access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/${APP}-error.log;

    # set a custom header for requests
    # add_header X-Served-By www-ec2-01;

    location    / {
      proxy_pass  http://$APP;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      proxy_set_header Host \$http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto \$scheme;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For \$remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port \$server_port;
      proxy_set_header X-Request-Start \$msec;
    }

    include $DOKKU_ROOT/$APP/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

    # Proxy download 
    location ~* ^/internal_redirect/(.*?)/(.*) {
    # Do not allow people to mess with this location directly
    # Only internal redirects are allowed
    internal;

    # Location-specific logging
    access_log logs/internal_redirect.access.log main;
    error_log logs/internal_redirect.error.log warn;

    # Extract download url from the request
    set $download_uri \$2;
    set $download_host \$1;

    # Compose download url
    set $download_url http://\$download_host/\$download_uri;

    # Set download request headers
    proxy_set_header Host \$download_host;
    proxy_set_header Authorization '';

    # The next two lines could be used if your storage 
    # backend does not support Content-Disposition 
    # headers used to specify file name browsers use 
    # when save content to the disk
    proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
    add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="\$args"';

    # Do not touch local disks when proxying 
    # content to clients
    proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

    # Download the file and send it to client
    proxy_pass \$download_url;
  }
}
```

The dokku docs tell me to escape '$' with a single \, so I did that.

Can a nginx wiz tell a nginx n00b what is wrong with the above template?

Dokku outputs the following error:

```
remote: nginx: [emerg] unknown log format "main" in /home/dokku/everseller/nginx.conf:117
remote: nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test failed
```

Thanks!

==== updated conf ====

```
# Special characters - dollar signs, spaces inside of quotes, etc. -
# should be escaped with a single backslash or can cause deploy failures.

server {
  listen      [::]:80;
  listen      80;
  server_name $NOSSL_SERVER_NAME;
  access_log  /var/log/nginx/${APP}-access.log;
  error_log   /var/log/nginx/${APP}-error.log;

  # set a custom header for requests
  # add_header X-Served-By www-ec2-01;

  location    / {
    proxy_pass  http://$APP;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
    proxy_set_header X-Request-Start $msec;
  }

  include $DOKKU_ROOT/$APP/nginx.conf.d/*.conf;

  # Proxy download 
  location ~* ^/internal_redirect/(.*?)/(.*) {
  # Do not allow people to mess with this location directly
  # Only internal redirects are allowed
  internal;

  # Location-specific logging
  access_log logs/internal_redirect.access.log main;
  error_log logs/internal_redirect.error.log warn;

  # Extract download url from the request
  set $download_uri $2;
  set $download_host $1;

  # Compose download url
  set $download_url http://$download_host/$download_uri;

  # Set download request headers
  proxy_set_header Host $download_host;
  proxy_set_header Authorization '';

  # The next two lines could be used if your storage 
  # backend does not support Content-Disposition 
  # headers used to specify file name browsers use 
  # when save content to the disk
  proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
  add_header Content-Disposition 'attachment; filename="$args"';

  # Do not touch local disks when proxying 
  # content to clients
  proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;

  # Download the file and send it to client
  proxy_pass $download_url;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Dollar signs indicate variables. So if used somewhere *not* indicating a variable they should be escaped.

Your config contains a lot of variables, where the dollar signs should *not* be escaped, e.g. 
`proxy_set_header Upgrade \$http_upgrade;` 
should be 
`proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;`

`proxy_set_header Host \$http_host;`  should read  `proxy_set_header Host $http_host;` and so forth.

By the way: I'm not a wiz ;-)

Comment: Thanks :-). Got a new error now. [emerg] invalid number of arguments in "proxy_set_header" directive in /home/dokku/everseller/nginx.conf:99. Again, what's a n00b to do? :-) I have edited my original question with the updated conf.

Comment: Well, I dont't know anything about dokku, but g00gle gives me this:  https://github.com/dokku/dokku/issues/1059  So you could try to comment out (# at the beginning of the line) "proxy_set_header ..."

Comment: I wasn't escaping special characters properly. Thanks!

Comment: So, does it work now?   Answer accepted? --> 'Click' :)

Comment: Well, the backslashes need to be present after all since it was a template that was being parsed. You put me on the right track but technically your answer is not the right one.